# How to create a list corresponding to each number from 2 to 100 that will contain numbers from an array that are its multiples?

Tags: java, logic

Recently i came across this question and could not figure out an optimal solution for it.

Suppose we have an array of numbers of any range like 9,-3,0,4,11,2,-8,.....
We need to print numbers from 2 to 100 and corresponding to each of them we need to print a list of numbers from the array such that the number in the array is divisible by it.
Example:
Using the existing array in example,
`2 -> 4,2,-8,...`
`3 -> -3,9,...`
`4 -> 4,-8,...`
and like this upto 100.

I tried working out the solution by dividing each number of the array by numbers from 2 to 100 and subsequently creating the list corresponding to each of them. But that didn't seem to me an optimal solution.

I even tried grouping numbers like a number which is divisible by 8 will be divisible by 2 and 4 so we don't need to divide it again. This would reduce some operations and complexity but would in turn, require creating such groups.

Please can anyone help finding an optimal solution for this problem by reducing the need to divide each number by 2 to 100.

Comment: Could you please show your work by providing a [MCVE]? Also... It would be helpful to see more rules or examples.

Comment: What do we need to do if there are two equal numbers in the list? 1) show it once 2) show it as many times as it's in the list? The optimal solution looks to me like working with prime factorization.

Comment: The question is also about the order of the items in the group. Is it sufficient to show them according to the order in the original list or not?

Comment: @SergeyProsin We can assume the array already contains distinct elements. And please could you explain how to go forward with prime factorization? Also the order doesn't matter. We just need to generate the list.

Comment: @Sometowngeek I don't have any code for this now. But i can show some examples. Example `array[] = {3,5,1,-7,6,34,88,2,-8,9,10,4,33}` Then output should be: `2 -> 6,34,88,2,-8,10,4` `3->3,6,9,33` `4->88,-8,4` `5->5,10` and similarly until 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the given problem I would choose one of the two following approaches:

**Version 1**

Two simple nested loops in combination with the method `map.computeIfAbsent`

```
int[] myArray = {3,5,1,-7,6,34,88,2,-8,9,10,4,33};
Map<Integer,List<Integer>> version1 = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 2; i< 100; i++){
    for(int x : myArray){
        if(x%i==0)
           version1.computeIfAbsent(i, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(x);
    }            
}
System.out.println(version1);
```

**Version 2**

A solution only with stream operations

```
    Map<Integer,List<Integer>> version2 = Arrays.stream(myArray).distinct().boxed()
            .flatMap(p -> IntStream.range(2, 100).filter(i -> p%i ==0).boxed()
                    .map(l->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(l,p)))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));

    System.out.println(version2);
```

There are certainly more elegant solutions or solutions that are optimal in terms of complexity. But I think the approaches here are short and easy to read.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep each sublist as you go, you can use previous results to limit the length of the list:

```
    List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    lists.add(list); // at 0: never used
    lists.add(list);
    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; ++i) {
        for (int j = i/2; j > 0; --j) {
            if (i%j == 0) {
                lists.add(extractMultiples(lists.get(j), i));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; ++i) {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + lists.get(i));
    }
```

with method `extractMultiples`:

```
public static List<Integer> extractMultiples(List<Integer> list, int n) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int x: list) {
        if (x%n == 0) {
            result.add(x);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```